# Is there a way to have macro check if a specific filter option exists?

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am trying to create a macro that will filter data based on the month, quarter, or year-to-date. I have a column in my spreadsheet called "MONYR" which includes the month and year that data point was taken from. The problem that I am having is that I might not always have data for each month. For example, the code below keeps triggering a "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class" because there is no "Jan-2019" option in the MONYR field as I am missing that data. Is there a way to make the macro check if the "Jan-2019" option exists, and if it doesn't, to move on to the next line without throwing an error?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONYR")

            .PivotItems("Jan-2019").Visible = True
            .PivotItems("Feb-2019").Visible = True
            .PivotItems("Mar-2019").Visible = True
            .PivotItems("Apr-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("May-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Jun-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Jul-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Aug-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Sep-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Oct-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Nov-2019").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Dec-2019").Visible = False
        
End With
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the rare cases where it is useful to use `On Error Resume Next` - but don't forget to put the statement `On Error Goto 0`.

`On Error Resume Next` tells VBA to continue code execution even if an error occurs. This is bad in most circumstances as it hides errors (and therefore problems with your code). But if you know exactly that a specific line *can* cause an error and it is okay to continue, this statement can help you out. But once these statements are done, you should change it back to the default behavior.

```
    On Error Resume Next    ' Skip to next line if pivot entry doesn't exist.
    .PivotItems("Jan-2019").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("Feb-2019").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("Mar-2019").Visible = True
    (...)
    On Error Goto 0
```